# Is the system represented by the equation $y(t) = x(2t)$ time invariant?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I came across this problem in the text book *Signals and Systems - Oppenheim* (Example-1.16).

To solve this, I followed the following algorithm (described in the book earlier for a separate problem):

$$\begin{align}
y(t) &=x(2t)\\
y_1(t)&=x_1(2t)\end{align}$$

Let $x_2(t)=x_1(t-t_0)$ and
$y_2(t)=x_2(2t)$

$$\begin{align}
\implies y_2(t) &= x_1(2(t - t_0))\\
&= x_1(2t-2t_0)\end{align}$$

Now, $y_1(t-t_0) = x_1(2(t-t_0)) = x_1(2t - 2t_0)$.

Since $y_2(t)$ and $y_1(t-t_0)$ are equivalent, the system should be *time-invariant*.

However, the book takes a different(graphical) approach, wherein the time-shifted $y(t)$,  $y(t - t _0)$ is $x(2t - t_0)$ and the resulting system is *time-varying*.

I would like to understand why is there this inconsistency between the mathematical and the graphical approach.

Comment: why on earth do you do things like `$y_2$$(t)$ $and$ $y_1$$(t-t_0)$` ?? `and` should be plaintext, and it's not only superfluous to put every single math mode element in `$`, it's also bad for readability! correcting that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your solution:

I followed the following algorithm:

$$ y(t) =x(2t) $$
$$ y_1(t) = x_1(2t)$$

Let  $$x_2(t) = x_1(t-t_0)  ~~~\text{and}~~~ y_2(t) = x_2(2t) $$

On this following step (time sampling of the shifted argument) you make the **usual** mistake:

$$\implies y_2(t) = x_1(2(t - t_0))$$ **which should instead be** :
$$\implies y_2(t) = x_2(2t) = x_1(t - t_0)|_{t=2t} = x_1(2t - t_0)$$

The remaining parts follow as usual to show that the time scaler is a time-varying system...

Answer (score 5):

there is not such inconsistency between the mathematical and the graphical approach, because the correct mathematical approach should be
$$ x_2(t) = x_1(t-t_0) $$
$$ y_2(t) = x_2(2t) = x_1(2t-t_0)$$
as the formula says, the factor only multiplies the variable, it is like saying 
$ f(x) = x + 2 $ so $ f(2x) $ will be equal to $ 2(x) + 2 $ and not  $2(x+2) $

I hope it answered your question

Comment: It did. You explained it really well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply delay, then apply system function

$x(t)$ $\rightarrow$ delay $t_0$ $\rightarrow$ $x(t-t_0)$ $\rightarrow$ apply system function (which doubles the time variable) $\rightarrow$ $x(2t-t_0)$

2. Apply system function, then apply delay

$x(t)$ $\rightarrow$ apply system function $\rightarrow$ $x(2t)$ $\rightarrow$ delay $t_0$ $\rightarrow$ $x(2(t-t_0)) = x(2t-2t_0)$

Since the outputs don't match, the system is time variant.